Optimization involving inverse function
Let $f:[0,1]\rightarrow[0,1]$ be a strictly increasing twice-differentiable function, with $f(0)=0$ and $f(1)=1$, and let $a \in (0,1)$.
I'm interested in finding a function $f$ that minimizes $f^{-1}(a)$ with some inequality constraint, i.e.
$$
\max_{t\in[0,1]} |f''(t)| \leq K
$$
for some $K>0$.
In a more intuitive sense, I'm interested in finding a position function that reaches some value $a \in (0,1)$ as quickly as possible, while keeping the maximum acceleration below some constant $K$.
I've found it very hard to find anything involving the inverse in optimization. I'm okay with making more assumptions on $f$, i.e. that $f$ is a polynomial, if the question is too general.
I'm also interested in further constraints, like $f''(0)=0, f'(0)=v_0, f'(1)=v_1$ with $v_0,v_1 \in \mathbb{R}$ for example, or if this generalizes to other derivatives of position (like jerk).
